# Replace string with values from multidimensional array based on a key

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace, multidimensional-array

I have a variable with multiple number stored as a string:

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 5";
```

and multidimensional array with other stored values:

```
$ar[1] = array('title#1', 'filename#1');
$ar[2] = array('title#2', 'filename#2');
$ar[3] = array('title#3', 'filename#3');
$ar[4] = array('title#4', 'filename#4');
$ar[5] = array('title#5', 'filename#5');
```

My goal is to replace number from `$string` with related tiles from `$ar` array based on associated array key. For an example above I should to get:

```
$string = "title#1, title#2, title#3, title#5";
```

I have tried to loop through `$ar` and do str_replace on `$string`, but final value of `$string` is always latest title from related array.

```
foreach($ar as $key => $arr){
  $newString = str_replace($string,$key,$arr[0]);
}
```

Any tips how to get this solved?

Thanks

Comment: In which point is off topic? I'm stuck on something which I'm not able to solve (my code is not working as I expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by `str_replace` by concat each time or you can do it by explode and concat.

Try Like this:

```
$string = "1, 2, 3, 5";
$arrFromString = explode(',', $string);
$newString = '';
foreach($ar as $intKey => $arr){
    foreach($arrFromString as $intNumber){
        if($intKey == $intNumber) {
            $newString .= $arr[0].',';
        }
    }
}
$newString = rtrim($newString,',');
echo $newString;
```

Output:

```
title#1,title#2,title#3,title#5
```

[live demo](https://eval.in/181757)

Comment: Well, your example is not a solution in my case because you are using values from array `$ar` not a keys of that array to get right title, which btw can be "Title of the product" without a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) functions to get the numbers in `$string` as an array and to combine the titles into a string respectively:

```
$res = array();
foreach (explode(", ", $string) as $index) {
     array_push($res, $ar[$index][0]);
}
$string = implode(", ", $res);
print_r($string);
```

will give you

```
title#1, title#2, title#3, title#5;
```

Comment: Requires little bit of modification to get result as as string not an array, but will work too in my case. Thanks!